# Using variable with register: error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm getting this error when I try to build this code:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling [Inputs]...
1>assign2.asm(12): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
1>assign2.asm(13): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
```

It happens when I try to subtract `ml1337skillz` from `usPop` and store that result into `Difference`.  I'm using `eax` as a temporary register for it.

```
TITLE Learning      (learning.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
usPop DWORD 313900000d               ; 32-bit
my1337Sk1LLz WORD 1337h              ; 16-bit
Difference SWORD ?                   ; 16-bit

.code
main PROC
 FillRegs:
    mov eax,usPop           ;load 3139000000d into eax    ; fine
    sub eax,my1337Sk1LLz    ;subtracts 1337h from usPop in eax  ; error #1
    mov Difference, eax     ;stores eax into Difference         ; error #2

    call DumpRegs           ;shows Registers

    exit                    ;exits
    main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two lines are your problem:

```
sub eax,my1337Sk1LLz    ;subtracts 1337h from usPop in eax
mov Difference, eax     ;stores eax into Difference
```

`eax` is 32 bits, but both `my1337Sk1LLz` and `Difference` are 16 bits.

There are two ways you might get around this:

1. **Changing the size of `my1337Sk1LLz` and `Difference`.** Right now you have the types as `WORD` and `SWORD`, respectively. You can change those to `DWORD` and `SDWORD` to make them 32-bit.
2. **Zero-extending and truncating.** You'll need another register. I'll use `edx` since you don't seem to be using it there. First, you'll need to sign-extend `my1337Sk1LLz`:

   ```
   movzx edx, my1337Sk1LLz  ; move, zero-extended, my1337Sk1LLz into EDX
   ```

   Then you can do the subtraction:

   ```
   sub eax, edx  ; they're the same size now so we can do this
   ```

   Then you can store the low word of `eax` into `Difference`, discarding the high word:

   ```
   mov Difference, ax
   ```

Comment: as usual, the problem is exactly what the assembler said it was :P

Comment: So what do I need to do to get this fixed?  Is there a way to allow a 16bit to take in a 32 bit variable?

Comment: @Shawn: You can't put 32 bits into 16 bits without losing the other 16 bits, but you can put a 16 bit value into a 32-bit register. I've edited my answer to show two possible fixes.

Comment: @icktoofay Thank you, you were a great deal of help and it is very much appreciated.  Works great now :)

Comment: Related: [Subtract a variable from a register? error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70911147) also explains the operand-size problem.  (But unlike this Q&A, doesn't talk about storing afterwards.  Note that the subtraction result won't fit in 16 bits in this case, so you *are* actually truncating some non-zero high bits.)