# Error A2022 Instruction operands must be the same size

Tags: assembly, x86

I get this error. "Instruction operands must be the same size

I believe it has something to do with the size of the variable "choice"

```
.data
    choice BYTE ?

mov choice, eax     ; error on this line
    call Crlf
    ret
DisplayMenu ENDP

DisplayOpr PROC USES edx
    mov eax, choice     ; error on this line
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: You allocate one byte of storage for `choice` but then try to store 4 bytes into it.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i believe I need to store 4 bytes

Comment: If you want to store 4 bytes into `choice`, then you need to make `choice` a `dword` variable.

Comment: When i replace BYTE with DWORD I get a linker error. Code LINK2005. How would i work around that?

Comment: Please post the full linker error, not just its code.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Using variable with register: error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16270280).  Or for this special case, also [Why can't I move directly a byte to a 64 bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22621340) re: movzx

Answer (score 0):

The register `eax` is 32-bits long, whereas `choice` is only a single `BYTE` (i.e. 8 bits).

You can change `choice` to be 32-bits long by declaring it as such:

```
choice DD 0AABBCCDDh
```

Alternatively, if `choice` is supposed to be a single byte long, you can use the 8-bit partial register `al`, which refers to the least significant byte of the register `EAX`:

```
mov al, choice
```

Comment: Usually to load a byte you want `movzx eax, byte ptr [choice]`, unless you specifically want to merge with whatever was in the upper part of EAX/RAX.